# How paraconsistent logicians solve the "Geach Paradox"?

Tags: logic, paradox, paraconsistency

Para consistent logic denies explosive law that (t and not-t) implies Y (Y is anything). 
However,we could construct a sentence,given any sentence Y,
  C   (C is true) implies Y 
and infering as follows:
1   (C is true) implies C
2,  (C is true) implies ((C is true) implies Y)
3   ((C is true) implies Y)
4   C
5   (C is true)
6   Y

And if we want to reject the argument,we have to reject (X implies(X implies Y))implies(X implies Y)——a so self-contained principle.

Comment: This is generally called the [Curry paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%27s_paradox) - I've not heard it attributed to Geach before. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: They invalidate contraction, see [IEP, Paraconsistent Logic](https://www.iep.utm.edu/para-log/). Slaney called such logics "Curry paraconsistent".

Answer (score 2):

*Below I'll refer to the paradox - namely, the problem arising from sentences of the form "If this sentence is true, then X" - as Curry's paradox, which I believe [is standard](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/curry-paradox/).*

Note that this isn't really a problem with paraconsistent logic per se, but rather a general problem with natural-language reasoning which shifting to paraconsistent logic alone doesn't solve.

The most obvious response is that we shouldn't allow statements of the form "If this statement is true, then X" in the first place. At that point there isn't an issue at all. If however we do want to allow them, then indeed adopting a paraconsistent stance isn't enough. Instead, [**relevance logics**](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-relevance/) are particularly relevant here (hehe). As you observe, a key point is the need to drop the **contraction** rule [X->(X->Y)]->(X->Y). This is a rather big deal - and I think most logicians lean solidly on the side of not wanting to allow Curry-style sentences in the first place - but it is studied, and regardless of one's philosophical stance leads to some interesting stuff. As to sources, [this bibliography](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-relevance/#BooRelLogIntFie) lists a number of good texts of various levels of technicality.